# Indeterminate ProgressBar while loading content for PreferenceFragment's ListPreference

Tags: android, optimization, android-fragments, android-preferences

In my PreferenceFragment there is a ListPreference which is programmatically populated at onCreate(). Thus, there is a little lag at the fragment start. In order to avoid it I would like to populate the ListPreference only when the preference has been pressed, and put a indeterminate ProgressBar while the content is loading.

How could I implement this? Do I really need to rewrite the adapter? How can I get the view for the ListPreference to pass to View.OnClickListener?

I hope this is not a trivial question, I have googled for a while but I didn't understand how should I actually implement the whole thing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation right now. Were you able to find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 7):

I've created a custom `PreferenceFragment` for this.

You can extend this one instead of a `PreferenceFragment` and delay your call to `addPreferencesFromResource` till after all loading is done, which will then hide the `ProgressBar` and display your content.

```
public class ProgressBarPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    private FrameLayout progress;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        showLoading((ViewGroup) view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPreferencesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.addPreferencesFromIntent(intent);

        hideLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public void addPreferencesFromResource(int preferencesResId) {
        super.addPreferencesFromResource(preferencesResId);

        hideLoading();
    }

    private void hideLoading() {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) getView();
        if ((root != null) && (progress != null)) {
            root.removeView(progress);
        }
    }

    private void showLoading(ViewGroup root) {
        progress = new FrameLayout(root.getContext());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        progress.addView(new ProgressBar(root.getContext()), lp);
        LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        root.addView(progress, lp2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `AsyncTask` to populate your ListPreference asynchronously and then remove the indeterminate progress bar upon completion.

First, extend AsyncTask like so:

```
private class PopulateListPreferenceTask extends AsyncTask<CharSequence, Void, Void> {
 protected Long doInBackground(CharSequence... entries) {
     // Code to populate ListPreference in here
 }

 protected void onPostExecute() {
     // Add code here if necessary to retrieve the progress bar view, i.e. findViewById
     myIntederminateProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

}

Have your indeterminate progress bar shown initially. Then, in your fragment's `onActivityCreated` method, call:

```
new PopulateListPreferenceTask().execute(/*CharSequence entries go here*/);
```

A couple notes:

- I am assuming that you would want to provide `Charsequence`s as
  input, but you can use any other type.
- If you need the AsyncTask to    receive the Activity context you can
  overload the constructor to    receive it as a parameter and then
  store it in a field.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I didn't understand how to make the indeterminate progress bar shown initially. Secondly I couldn't find any documentation for the activityCreateView method.

Comment: Edited my response (meant onActivityCreated not activityCreateView). Are you creating your progress bar programmatically or in the layout XML?

Comment: I am used to define UI elements in the XMLs. I thought to create a new RelativeLayout and bind it to the ListPreference dialog content placeholder. Is it right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having a problem showing the progress bar initially. If you post your code where you're trying to display it I could give feedback.

Comment: @EricaCooksey in PreferenceFragments you don't have a layout xml to inflate, Android inflates it for you, instead you create a preferences xml that only have pref items, so it's a bit trickier then in regular activities/fragments. See my answer